# puppet agent not daemonized while docs say its default

Tags: debian, puppet, stretch

It seems that after newly installing the puppet-agent on several debian 9 stretch nodes that the agent is automatically closed after a certain amount of time, while in the docs puppet state that default the agent is daemonized already.

Is there anybody else experiencing this?

there is some sort of process running but I dont think this is the actual puppet agent right?

`root       805  0.0  0.8 231160 17768 ?        Sl   18:45   0:00 /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/ruby /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/mcollectived --config=/etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/server.cfg --pidfile=/var/run/puppetlabs/mcollective.pid --daemonize`

Comment: How are you starting the agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about this process: it is the mcollective daemon, provided by the `puppet-agent` package.

Do you have any puppet related logs in `/var/log/{daemon,syslog,messages}` that you could post here to give more details ?

Maybe also in `/var/log/kern.log` in case it's a memory problem and oom-killer has joined the party ?

Comment: thank you for your answer.

There is no oom in any of the log fles, the puppet logs are spam because I am still testing my module and everything is red in there hehe :P

Comment: Note that although mcollectived may be packaged with the agent, it is a largely separate thing.  The agent does not depend on it.

Comment: can you put here the last lines shown by puppet before it exits ?

Comment: so currently the agent is on:

```root       722  0.0  2.7 179760 54732 ?        Ssl  18:58   0:01 /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/ruby /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet agent --no-daemonize```

I will wait until its down